# PayPal Recurring Payments - Mock sign in for testing

Tags: php, paypal, recurring

I'm using the PayPal recurring payments API. I was wondering whether it was possible to do a 'mock' sign in for testing purposes on the sandbox, so that I can also have test routines subsequent to the 'SetExpressCheckoutDetails' and 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails' API calls. I'm using the PHP SDK.

TIA

Comment: If you go to developer.paypal.com, you can create a developer account and manage your test accounts. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: they have a great sandbox -use it.

Comment: I'm using the sandbox; but I'm doing automated tests to ensure that everything is working properly, and can't sign in everytime manually with my fake sandbox business account to continue the payment process. So I was wondering if there's some way of faking the sign in with my fake account!